# Test service class using moq in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I have a service class like this:

```cs
public class CategoryService: ICategoryService
{
    private myContext _context;
    public CategoryService(myContext context)
    {
         _context = context;
    }
        
    public async Task<List<CategoryDTO>> GetCategories()
    {  
            
        return (await _context.Categories.ToListAsync()).Select(c => new CategoryDTO
        {
              CategoryId = c.CategoryId, 
              CategoryName = c.CategoryName
                
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

My context looks like this:

```cs
public DbSet<Category> Categories {get;set;}
```

My unit test for `GetCategories()` is:

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestGetCategories()
{      
    //Arrange
    Mock <myContext> moq = new Mock <myContext>();
 
    var moqSet = new Mock<DbSet<Category>>();
             
    moq.Setup(m => m.Categories).Returns(moqSet.Object);
                
    CategoryService service = new CategoryService(moq.Object);

    //Act
    var result = service.GetCategories();

    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);

 }
```

But I am getting error for my unit test. It says:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: m => m.Categories

Can someone help me to fix the Setup part?

Comment: Have you considered to use one of the following nuget packages to ease the pain of EF mocking: [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing), [EntityFrameworkCore3Mock](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core3-mock) ? As a prerequisite please make your `DbSet` property `virtual`.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I will try it.

Comment: @PeterCsala thank you so much for your help. "EntityFrameworkCore3Mock" was really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally could figure it out.
As @PeterCsala mentioned, we can use "EntityFrameworkCore3Mock"
You can find it here: https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core3-mock

My unit test looks like this:

```
public DbContextOptions<ShoppingCartContext> dummyOptions { get; } = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ShoppingCartContext>().Options;

[Fact]
public async Task TestGetCategories()
{
     //Arrange
     var dbContextMoq = new DbContextMock<ShoppingCartContext>(dummyOptions);

     //Create list of Categories
     dbContextMoq.CreateDbSetMock(x => x.Categories, new[]
     {
         new Category { CategoryId = 1, CategoryName = "Items" },
         new Category { CategoryId = 2, CategoryName = "Fruits" }
     });

     //Act
     CategoryService service = new CategoryService(dbContextMoq.Object);
     var result = await service.GetCategories();

     //Assert
     Assert.NotNull(result);

}
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. The credit goes to @huysentruitw.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Moq with non overrideable properties. It needs to be either abstract or virtual and that's why you get the error.

Change the `dbcontext` property `Categories` to virtual and try again.

```
public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories {get;set;}
```

P.s. you don't need to do this when you mock interface methods,  because they are inherently overridable.

Comment: thank you for the answer but I get another error that says: "InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class"

Comment: The reason you get that is that Moq needs an accessible constructor to create the mocked instance. If you don't have a parameterless constructor you need to provide the constructor arguments when creating the mock.